# Que pasa si me dice error al instalar el modulo de discord.py en el cmd de Windows

Tags: python, cmd, discord.py

Al yo querer instalar el modulo de discord.py con el comando `pip install discord.py` me sale lo siguiente

```html
C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ>pip install discord.py
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (786 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\TORREC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4payffcj'
       cwd: C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ajsjpbec\aiohttp_f6d9ef4332174db6a17fb3d434d544e1
  Complete output (25 lines):
  Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: unexpected end of data (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
  running dist_info
  creating C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info
  writing C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  creating 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-73kjefex\aiohttp.dist-info'
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/f5/90ede947a3ce2d6de1614799f5fea4e93c19b6520a59dc5d2f64123b032f/aiohttp-3.7.4.post0.tar.gz#sha256=493d3299ebe5f5a7c66b9819eacdcfbbaaf1a8e84911ddffcdc48888497afecf (from https://pypi.org/simple/aiohttp/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\TORRECILLA_MARTÍNEZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\TORREC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4payffcj' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Luego de esto lo que sucede es que se intentan volver a descargar lo que se descargó al inicio y vuelve a dar el error y así un bucle sin fin. Quien me ayuda plis D:

Comment: lo recomendable es trabajar en un entorno virtual. Siempre existe la posibilidad de cargarte a tu S.O. XD

Comment: El problema era del computador, debido a que lo formateé hace poco y pues como que algo salió mal pero lo volví a formatear y todo Good